# How to use a mutex/critical section within a member function inside a DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, com, mutex, atl

I'm creating a COM class (with ATL) that resides inside a DLL.  For one of my member functions, depending on certain conditions, I'd like to potentially use a third-party library (Adobe's XMP SDK), which must be initialized and terminated.  So basically, I'll have a member function which looks sort of like this:

```
void CMyClass::MyMemberFunction()
{
    SXMPMeta::Initialize();

    // ...

    SXMPMeta::Terminate();
}
```

Now according to the Adobe XMP library docs,

> You must call the initialization and termination functions in a
>   single-threaded manner . . . .

Meanwhile, I believe that File Explorer may create multiple instances of my class on separate threads. So if I understand things correctly, it sounds like I'll have a critical section and I'll need to use mutexes around the library initialization and termination (but please correct me if that's wrong).

I'm unclear on how to go about this. I wasn't sure if I should use one of the [ATL critical section classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/threading-models-and-critical-sections-classes?view=vs-2019) or perhaps CRITICAL_SECTION. CRITICAL_SECTION seemed like a nice option, but the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-critical-section-objects) shows it being initialized in main().  What happens if you're in a DLL?  I'd prefer not to start messing with DllMain().  Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Per Gem's suggestion, I tried the following:

```
struct XMPLibraryInitializer
{
    XMPLibraryInitializer()
    {
        // Initialize libraries
        if (!SXMPMeta::Initialize() || !SXMPFiles::Initialize())
        {
            XMP_StringPtr pszErrorMessage = "Libraries failed to load";
            throw XMP_Error(kXMPErr_InternalFailure, pszErrorMessage);
        }
        ATLTRACE("\nXMP library initialized on thread %lu\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
    ~XMPLibraryInitializer()
    {
        // Terminate XMP libraries
        SXMPFiles::Terminate();
        SXMPMeta::Terminate();
        ATLTRACE("\nXMP library terminated on thread %lu\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
};

HRESULT MyFunc()
{
    // Statically initialize the Adobe XMP library
    try
    {
        static XMPLibraryInitializer xmpLibraryInitializer;
    }
    catch (const XMP_Error & e)
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    // ...

}
```

This seems to operate fine, except the output I see is

> XMP library initialized on thread 5820
>   ...
>   XMP library terminated on thread 3104

Is there any explanation for the different thread numbers? And if the numbers are different, does that mean it doesn't comply with the docs requiring single threaded initialization and termination?

Comment: Explorer does not do that, it does not require extensions to be thread-safe.  Mostly because that would make writing shell extensions correctly very hard to do.  So it takes care of it by itself, ensuring that all calls are made from the same thread (aka "apartment threading").

Comment: Oh, then maybe my whole premise is mistaken.  To test it out, I printed GetCurrentThreadId() from my class's FinalConstruct(), and it seemed to print out a couple different numbers.  Do you know why that might be?  Additional info: my class is a property handler, and I navigated to a folder with a bunch of different files to get a readout. Additional info: I'm a novice, so I have very little idea what I'm doing.

Comment: So what may be happening is that it is being constructed on first use on whatever thread that happens to be, then it is destructed on program exit which is most likely the program's main thread, though there is much discussion on whether it could be the program's last-exiting thread, usually the main  thread, but not necessarily on all architectures. Usually this is good enough for objects that need to be initialised in a "single-thread/thread-saved" manner but can then be used on multiple threads. The object can't keep any thread-specific state if it is to be used from multiple threads.

Comment: Okay, as long as it doesn't leak resources or otherwise cause crashes, I'm cool with it.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple static singleton function should suffice, if you want to keep hold of it until the program exits. 
The static initialisation is guaranteed to be only done one in an efficient thread-safe manner (from C++11) usually involving a mutex double-check of a guard flag.

You would call it every place where you can't be sure you already have the ATX set up. There is no point, but no harm, in calling it in the middle of some repeated transaction. So do call it in GiveMeAToken() but don't call it in UseToken() because you know it must have been called in order to get the token?

I updated this to show how a simple bool Initialise success status can be kept, though the actual return from SXMPMeta::Initialize() may be more complex:

```
struct SomeATXThing
{
    bool good;
    SomeATXThing()
    {
        good = SXMPMeta::Initialize();
    }
    ~SomeATXThing()
    {
        if (good)
            SXMPMeta::Terminate();
    }
};

SomeATXThing* AtxEnsureSingleton()
{
    static SomeATXThing someATXThing;
    return someATXThing.good ? &someATXThing : nullptr;
}
```

Note one caveat with singletons is that they are destructed in reverse order to the end of their construction. Some other independently earlier constructed singleton MUST NOT rely on the existence of this singleton during its destruction, but it is safe for one singleton constructor to invoke another during construction and again during destruction. There is no easy enforcement of this rule, except ABEND.

You can do phoenix reactivation where the object (generally relying on undefined behaviour existence of object instance addresses after destruction), but it is a load of grief.

Comment: One additional question: the initialization function returns a boolean to indicate success or failure. Is there a way to signal that success or failure back to the object construction part?

Comment: The only way a c'tor can report an error is by means of throwing an exception. Since you are implementing a COM object I assume that you are handling C++ exceptions already, so that they never cross the COM ABI.

Comment: @loop123123 Or you add a member to the SomeATXThing object, that gets set by the constructor. Depending on your mood you could have the singleton function return a null pointer if it failed to initialise. Note that you can put anything else that makes sense in that object.

Comment: Updated on the basis that SXMPMeta::Initialize returns a simple bool status, though it is probably something more complex.